# How to format get param by split on ^ in jsp by using jslt tag or java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, split

I want to format string which come from url its physicianName in jsp.

This physicianName has string HL7 Format of Referring doctor name => Family Name^Given Name^Middle Name^Prefix^Suffix to Prefix Family Name, Given Name Middle Name.

```
    <c:set var="phy_name" scope="application"
            value="${param.physicianName}" />

//@@todo formatting to Prefix Family Name, Given Name Middle Name.
```

This might be simple but I am new to jsp.

It would be great if anyone can give other solution by jsp (<% %>) tag with java code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

to replace `^` with a (space), you could do something like this :

```
<c:set var="phy_name" value="${fn:replace(param.physicianName,'^', ' ')}" />
```

To exactly format the name in the following way :

```
 Prefix Family Name, Given Name Middle Name.
```

you can just use scriptlet tag and code in java, something like this :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>


<%
  String tmp[] =  param.physicianName.split(^);
  String formatedPhyName = tmp[3]+" "+tmp[0]+", "+tmp[1]+" "+tmp[2];
%>
<p>Phy name : ${formatedPhyName}</p>
```

Comment: It giving me error phy_name cannot be resolved at line `String tmp[] =  phy_name.split(^);`

Comment: I have edited the answer try now with the new line added and also dont forget to add `taglib` directive line in the begging of the file.

Comment: I kept above code as is in my jsp page but it still giving me same error. Do i need to use pageContext.getAttribute?

Comment: I have edited again, Use only the second part of my answer, the one with the `<%` ... `%>`

Comment: I have resolved issue and its working now with code below `String physicianNameStr = request.getParameter("physicianName");
  if(physicianNameStr != "" || physicianNameStr != null){
   String tmp[]  =   physicianNameStr.split("\\^");
   String formatedPhyName = tmp[3]+" "+tmp[0]+", "+tmp[1]+" "+tmp[2];
   pageContext.setAttribute("formatedPhyName",formatedPhyName);
  }`